# Get smoke simulation to observe emitter's pose?

Tags: physics, armature, smoke-simulation

Right now I am making a model of a wind elemental in blender, and was trying to use the smoke simulation to make a small whirlwind that swirls around its main body.

However, the smoke simulation doesn't appear to observe the emitter mesh's current pose.  Rather than emitting from the model itself, it appears to emit from an invisible figure in a T-pose.

Is there a way to correct this problem, or is this something I should file a bug report on?

**EDIT:** I've rendered the first frame of the smoke simulation to show where it starts off from, in order to better demonstrate the issue:

[image: Wind Elemental]

Comment: It looks pretty low resolution. If you increase the resolution of the smoke sim, does that improve the result?

Comment: Yeah, already tried that, didn't work.

Comment: Also just now tried using key frames, to make it transition to the crouching position, but that didn't work either :-/

Comment: Is it possible you could upload your .blend? I just tried rigging a cube and using that in a smoke sim and it worked fine.

Comment: I had actually just uploaded a separate .blend file to blendswap, which also displayed the issue:  http://www.pasteall.org/blend/25773

Comment: As a note, this happens both with a manually-created smoke system, and by creating one automatically from Object->Quick Effects->Quick Smoke

Comment: What version of blender are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 2.69

Comment: I have looked at everything I could think of and I don't see any difference between the files. [Here's the file I made](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/25774) which is working, does it work for you?

Comment: Yeah, I tried using your file and did work for me, but I am at a loss as to why.  What version are you using?

Comment: 2.69.. This is really strange..

Comment: Okay, at this point, I'm assuming it's a bug and will post a report for it.

Comment: At this point, I've determined that the issue is a bug, possibly a platform-specific one, and will be reporting it on the mantis bug tracker.

Comment: One additional note: I had no trouble getting it working on Blender 2.66a, which I believe is nearly a year old.

Answer (score 1):

I know the smoke sim has changed a lot recently, but it used to have a modifier on the modifier stack. It's possible that your smoke sim's modifier is above the armature modifier in the modifier stack, IWC the smoke sim is getting calculated, THEN the pose is getting calculated.

It also looks like the t-pose figure is a little bigger than the other. If that's the case, you should make sure your scale is applied on the model and the rig.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yeah, I already have the smoke sim's position below the armature modifier in the stack, it had been added to the very bottom of the stock.  And the reason the t-pose figure appears bigger is because the model is posed in a semi-crouching position.  I did check and the bounding box for the smoke domain did not have its scale applied, though applying the scale did not change anything.

Comment: Hmmm, I can't think of anything else, except that it's just not supported...which I find difficult to believe. I hope you figure it out :-/

Comment: I see no problems emitting smoke from an animated mesh if the armature modifier is before the smoke. If the modifiers are moved after the smoke sim has been baked you will need to free the bake to see the changes.